# cant load axios by using cdn

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch

I'm trying to use axios by cdn

but i'm getting this error :
Refused to load the script 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: And what did your research into [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) reveal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case loading axios cdn through pug base template, I created an express middleware which sets header of Content-Security-Policy.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) { 
  res.setHeader( 'Content-Security-Policy', "script-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com" ); 
  next(); 
})
```